# Semi-cartesian product of graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology

I was going through following article, where a new graph product named as Semi-cartesian product of graphs is introduced.

http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/757/art%253A10.1007%252Fs10910-013-0297-6.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2Fs10910-013-0297-6&token2=exp=1495368383~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F757%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252Fs10910-013-0297-6.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252Fs10910-013-0297-6*~hmac=edf0cf8704b407f3d1902aa2aff525986a4470dc3a40a8c5ed394c72ca607d18

[image]

The author considered bipartite graphs to define this product. Does it mean that we can not consider Semi-cartesian product of non-bipartite graphs??

Comment: The article appears to be behind a paywall.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Oh... Then let me add some screen shots

Comment: Looking at the definition, I can see that there must be some special reason why the author used bipartite graphs $G$ and $H$ to define the semi-cartesian product of $G$ and $H$.  However, what I am not so sure about is whether the condition that $G$ and $H$ are bipartite is *necessary* to ensure the existence of the semi-cartesian product of $G$ and $H$.  (That is, it might be possible to *extend* the notion of the semi-cartesian product to the case of non-bipartite graphs.)